# How to point a custom domain to a netlify function?

Tags: aws-lambda, netlify

Essentially, i have a netlify function that's at the path - `http://<auto-generated-name>.netlify.app/.netlify/functions/index`. I followed the instructions on the netlify dashboard to setup a custom domain, but with that setup, i have to go to `http://<custom-domain>.com/.netlify/functions/index` to access my app.

I want to set up my custom domain so that all requests to `http://<custom-domain>.com` **go DIRECTLY to the function, and NOT to the root `http://<auto-generated-name>.netlify.app` domain**. How do I do that?

Edit: I tried adding redirects in the `netlify.toml` file, and that does work, but I'm still curious if there's a way to "directly" point the domain to the function instead of redirecting requests.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps host a simple html page at `index.html` which runs some JS to call your function.

But most likely you just want to do a netlify redirect with the `200` [status code](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/redirect-options/#http-status-codes), as that configuration will leave the original URL intact and make it look like it is hosted and not being redirected.

Depending on your netlify and caching setup this would actually run on first page load, with the redirect effectively never happening.